# How to move location of postrgresql 13 database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am looking to move the location of a pgsql 13 database from it's default to another disk.

I initially followed this guide [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But this is for v9.5, not 13. My challenge is that the location of the database - found from running the below command - is also where the configuration files are stored.

```
SHOW data_directory;
     data_directory
------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/13/data
(1 row)

SHOW config_file;
     config_file
----------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

With version 9.5 the configuration files were in a separate area, so at this point I got stuck with the guide.

It seems if I want to move the database location I also have to move all the configuration files as well.

I have tried moving the entire data folder to the new location and restarting postgres but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*With version 9.5 the configuration files were in a separate area*" - no, the were not. Some Linux distribution however did separate the config files from the data directory. But e.g. on CentOS the config file is always located in the data directory.

Comment: "*I have tried moving the entire data folder to the new location and restarting postgres but no luck.*" that is the right approach, but you will need to change the service definition to use the new data directory. How you do that depends on your Linux distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your configuration files are located under $PG_DATA, where they belong:

---

1. Shut down the (old) database
2. Copy the data directory to the new location (use `cp -rp`, or `rsync -acv`, or `tar`, or `cpio`, ...) Make sure that file attributes and ownership are preserved by the copy. The `pgdata` directory should be mode == `0600`, and owner.group == `postgres.postgres`.
3. [optionally] rename the old data directory
4. [optionally] you may want to edit the configuration files at the new location
5. edit the startup file (in `/etc/init.d/postgresql` ) and make sure $PG_DATA points to the new location. [note: this is for ubuntu; other distributions may us a different starting mechanism]
6. Start the new database, and check if it runs (`ps auxw| grep postgres`, and if you can connect (`psql -U postgres postgres`)
7. [optionally] remove the directory tree at the old location.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, unfortunately there is no startup file in init.d relating to postgresql.

Comment: I found the file, it exists under /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-13.service.
Once I found it I followed your steps and this has sorted it, didn't have to edit the config file as it is looking at ConfigDir, which is set to the environment variable $PG_DATA.

Thanks for the help.